# Access PowerBi report offline. By storing its data or caching

Tags: caching, powerbi, offline

i have an app where i view/Create PowerBi Reports. I want to make a functionality such as
the **PowerBi reports** gets **stored or cached** and when i am offline then i can access the cached or stored PowerBi report.

Comment: Use .pbix files with imported data opened in Power BI Desktop.

Comment: i don,t want to use Power Bi Desktop as i have my own custom desktop app and in that app there's  already functionality to view the reports. But i don't want every time to make an API call for the reports, it should make API call only when forces refresh is made else it should get from cached or stored data.